# FIND and MID function results in text formatted answer

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I tried capturing the contents in a cell, removing the decimal point and the last digit.  Results worked, but it now a "text" result.

- e.g., B4 contains 145.35
- C4 cell is `=IF(IFERROR(FIND(".",B4),0)>0,MID(B4,FIND(".",B4)-1,1),"0")`, results 145
- D4 cell is `=IF(IFERROR(FIND(".",B4),0)>0,MID(B4,FIND(".",B4)+1,1),"0")`, results 3
- E4 cell is `=concatenate(c4,d4)`, results 1453

E4 will result in a text formatted answer.  I need this to be in a number format since I will be using for another formula.

Comment: Please note that [SU] is not a script writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (including any scripts you are using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: you should be able to do that with VBA code, look for string manipulation functions, google vb string manipulation

Comment: Did you try formatting the cell or column as a number?

Answer (score 1):

To coerce a text into a number, add a zero or multiply by one. Concatenate() is never really needed. The & operator is much shorter:

```
=(C4&D4)+0
```

Another approach: If you just want to cut off the decimal points you can use Int() instead of MID() and the result will be a number.

```
=Int(B4)
```

If you want to retain the first decimal character, multiply the value in B4 by 10, the cut off the decimals with Int()

```
=Int(B4*10)
```